# CNN+LSTM ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

currently making  human action recognition to detect a cheating kind on the exam from CCTV using AlexNet+LSTM

**My Data are raw images in each class folder with like** [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HpBLwcDe8Ifbfhe3yNGtPQkai-XsJ6xT?usp=sharing)

But I got error like this:

ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:830 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:813 run_step  *
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:770 train_step  *
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:989 __call__  *
    input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py:212 assert_input_compatibility  *
    raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)
```

The error comes when I do the `model.fit`.

From what I read it said that the problem at the input_shape but I am still doesn't found the solution to my problem
the link of **my code at collab can be found** [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D7grs6_WHxDYCo8UEwETKqp3V_10U51J?usp=sharing),

I still don't understand what is the problem, I check the documentation for input_shape in TimeDistributed and it's the same for (timeSteps, height, width, channels)

I did try to remaking the model but the problem is still the same

is it from my ImageDataGenerator?

I would appreciate if anybody has the experience in this matter and tries to help my problem

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The [TimeDistributed documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed) says the input should have shape `(batch, time, others . . .)`.  In your case (a batch of images in a time series), the shape should be `(batch, time, r, g, b)`.

But the image data generator in your code is reading images from a directory in a batch, outputting tensors with shape `(batch, r, g, b)`.  So you are missing the time dimension.

If you want to use `TimeDistributed` layers, then you'll need to assemble your images as a time-series, *then* apply batching.

Comment: hello thank you for your comment and sorry for the late reply, do you know where can i found how to assembles my images as time-series that you mentioned? bit lost here

Thank you so much

Comment: Do your images have some sort of temporal order to them?  For example, are they short video clips or something?

Comment: If your images are time-ordered, you will probably need to write your own data loader.  It would read all the images in a given time series and place them into a single tensor.   If your images are _not_ time-ordered, then you can just stop using the `TimeDistributed` layers :)

Comment: yes at first it's a short clips video, i make it into frame so i can sort it into each class folder

Comment: so it's better to just use the short clip video as input instead of the raw images then?

Comment: do you know what should i use to load the video? because i cant use the keras-video-generators, collab cant detect it i dont know why

Comment: I'm still not completely understanding.  Are you wanting to feed the whole video clip through the network?  or just a single frame?

Comment: at first i thought single frame would do the work, but i read some paper it should be video clip to train the model using AlexNet+LSTM so that the model can predict by checking from a few frames in a video, still wondering how to do it too actually...

Comment: When you say colab can't detect `keras-video-generators`, what do you mean?  Have you tried to pip install that library in colab and it didn't work?

Comment: If you can't find a pre-built library to do the job, you'll have to write your own custom data loader.  It will need to load the entire video clip into a tensor.  Probably the easiest approach is to loop over each frame and load it into a numpy array.  Then [`stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) the numpy arrays to get the whole video clip, then convert the stacked array to a tensor.